# How to plot this equation

Tags: matlab, plot

Please help me how to plot this equation `x2 = x1 + 2.5*cos(230*t)` by adjusting `t` as `t = 0:0.0001:.01`.

Comment: You have three variables. Is this 3D or is `x1` constant? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Presumably you looked in the MATLAB documentation. Did you learn anything from that? And if so, what?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a single line 2D plot and x1 is fixed, try

```
x1 = <put your number here>
t = 0:0.0001:.01
x2 = x1 + 2.5*cos(230*t)
plot(t, x2)
```

If you want something fancier like different formatting or a 3D plot, I highly recommend at least skimming through the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-8955.html).  For surface or mesh plotting, you'll want to look at `mesh`, `surface`, and probably `meshgrid`.  Matlab's rich support for plotting is one of its big selling points.